# Query all objects in active directory using LDAP, vbScript or PowerShell

Tags: powershell, vbscript, permissions, active-directory, inheritance

I'm hoping someone has already developed a script to do this.

I'm need to query all objects in AD (users, computers, containers (OU's), everything exceot for the forest root) and show which objects in AD do not have the "Include inheritable permissions from this object's parent" attribute checked.

Thanks much

Comment: SO is not a place to ask people to do your work for you or find solutions for you. Attempt to solve the problem on your own, post your code and explain where you get stuck, and people will try to help you get past it.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. Looks like you know exactly what you need to do, have you tried anything?

Comment: [José](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7622.jose-active-directory-reporting-free-tool.aspx) might be a starting point.

Comment: You're right tnw , my bad on that.  I did a copy/paste and looks like part of it got left out.  THere was more to my original post.

Comment: @alroc - Geez...I wasn't asking for anyone to do my work.  I simply didn't post the entire question (by accident).  Don't jump to conclusions.

Comment: So where's the question?

Comment: @alroc - Tried to post yesterday but wasn't able to.  Had to wait until today.  No real question now (I wasn't getting proper results back for containers when I queried AD), but I ended up finding the answer to my own question and better code (with minor tweaks).   (see code below)

Answer (score 1):

If you show some initiative, I can help in VBS. I wrote a VBS a while ago to query everything in AD for below attributes via LDAP, and putting results in Excel and plain text file.

- "objectCategory"
- "objectClass"
- "objectGUID"
- "objectSid"
- "sIDHistory"
- "sAMAccountName"
- "description"
- "sAMAccountType"
- "userAccountControl"
- "whenCreated"
- "whenChanged"
- "givenName"
- "sn"
- "displayName"
- "title"
- "mail"
- "physicalDeliveryOfficeName"
- "memberOf"
- "telephoneNumber"
- "mobile"
- "pager"
- "company"
- "lastLogon"
- "badPwdCount"
- "badPasswordTime"
- "streetAddress"
- "l"
- "postalCode"
- "st"
- "co"

I will show you my first 50/360 lines of code:

```
Const ADS_SCOPE_SUBTREE = 2
Const PageSize = 2000
Const GAP = "——————————————————————————————————————————————————"
'=== Public Variables ===
Dim aADProp, sRootLDAP, oRecordSet, oFSO, oLogFile, oExcel, oWB, oWS
Dim lObjects, lComputersEnabled, lUsersEnabled, lComputersDisabled, lUsersDisabled, lOtherDisabled, lExcelRow
Dim aUAC ' AD's UserAccountControl flags array
Dim aSAT ' AD's sAMAccountType flags array

'==================================================
Main
'==================================================
Sub Main
    Init
    ConnectAD
    If Err.Number = 0 Then ProcessRecords
    CleanUp
End Sub
'--------------------------------------------------
Sub Init
    Dim dNow
    dNow = Now
    Wscript.echo dNow & vbTab & "Init"
    DefineADProp
    DefineUACArray
    DefineSATArray
    Set oFSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
    Set oLogFile = oFSO.CreateTextFile(WScript.ScriptFullName & "_" & Join(Array(Year(dNow),Month(dNow),Day(dNow)),".") & ".log")
    sRootLDAP = "'LDAP://" & GetObject("LDAP://RootDSE").Get("defaultNamingContext") & "'"
    LogT vbCrlf & Q(WScript.ScriptFullName) & " started."
    Logg "RootLDAP: " & sRootLDAP
    Logg "Listing AD Attributes: " & Join(aADProp,", ")
    Logg GAP
    lObjects = 0
    lUsersEnabled = 0
    lUsersDisabled = 0
    lComputersEnabled = 0
    lComputersDisabled = 0
    lOtherDisabled = 0
    If Err.Number = 0 Then
        lExcelRow = 1
        Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        oExcel.visible = True
        Set oWB = oExcel.Workbooks.Add
        Set oWS = oWB.Worksheets(1)
        oWS.Cells(lExcelRow,1) = "distinguishedName"
        oWS.Range(oWS.Cells(lExcelRow,2),oWS.Cells(lExcelRow,UBound(aADProp)+2)) = aADProp
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you @PatricK - appreciate your input.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I made a mistake and didn't post the question initially.  When I posted originally, I wasn't able to enumerate all AD objects and had a question about that, but it is since been resolved and the code below works (in case anyone else needs it - sharing is OK).  No need to try and reinvent the wheel if the code already existed.  And many thanks to [Rems @ Petri](http://www.petri.co.il/forums/showthread.php?t=49638)

```
    '
    '//----------------------------- Code below -----------------------------//
    '

    Const SE_DACL_PROTECTED = &H1000

    Dim objRootDSE

    With WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Network")
       Set objRootDSE = GetObject ("LDAP://" & .UserDomain & "/RootDSE")
    End With

    strDomainDN = objRootDSE.Get("DefaultNamingContext")

    Set objCommand = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

    objConnection.Provider = "ADsDSOObject"
    objConnection.Open "Active Directory Provider"

    objCommand.ActiveConnection = objConnection
    objCommand.Properties("Searchscope") = 2 ' SUBTREE
    objCommand.Properties("Page Size") = 250
    objCommand.Properties("Timeout") = 30
    objCommand.Properties("Cache Results") = False
    objCommand.CommandText = "SELECT ADsPath FROM 'LDAP://" & strDomainDN & "'"

    Set objRecordSet = objCommand.Execute

    On Error Resume Next
    If Not objRecordSet.eof Then 
       objRecordSet.MoveFirst

       Do Until objRecordSet.EOF
         ModUser objRecordSet.Fields("ADsPath").Value
         objRecordSet.MoveNext
       Loop
    End If
    objRecordset.Close : objConnection.Close

    wscript.echo vbCrLf & "-- All done --" : wscript.quit 0

    Sub ModUser(strADsPath)
       Dim objUser, objNtSecurityDescriptor, intNtSecurityDescriptorControl

       Set objuser = GetObject(strADsPath)

       Set objNtSecurityDescriptor = objUser.Get("ntSecurityDescriptor")
       intNtSecurityDescriptorControl = objNtSecurityDescriptor.Control

       If (intNtSecurityDescriptorControl And SE_DACL_PROTECTED) Then
        Wscript.Echo objUser.sAMAccountName & " (" & objUser.distinguishedName & ") is NOT checked"
       End If
    End Sub
```